# how to handle http requests from a browser using c#

Tags: c#

I have a windows application developed in c#.Net which is used as a website blocker for a network.I have done this by modifying the hosts file.It works fine when urls are blocked like "www.yahoo.com".Now my requirement is I have to block the urls based on the keywords.i.e when the user just types "yahoo" in the browser,I should verify the keyword and block a corresponding website.Now how can I track the website typed by the user in the browser and block or allow the user to particular site based on the url.I should not allow the user to view the page if the keyword is present.How to do this?Can some one help me to do this?

Comment: You should use one of the free or for-pay products to do it.  There's not much point in reinventing the wheel - there are a half-dozen ways to get around your scheme in my head in the time it took me to type this comment.

Comment: You will have to redesign your methodology for this -- the hosts file is really not the right way to do this and, as you're finding, won't work for the new requirements you have.  You might not be able to do this in straight C#, since you might have to hook into other applications running on the box (IE, Firefox, etc.)

Comment: Apart from the fun in writing it in C# it would be pointless as this is done at the lower networking levels for intercepting addresses and checking the requests for a certain keywords which is what a transparent web proxy does for you. You would have to think in terms of the network stack where the interception takes place. It is not an impossible task but why do it as Tom Ritter pointed out in his comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's plenty of code samples out there that will act as proxies (eg. http://code.cheesydesign.com/?p=393) however I would strongly suggest following the advice of the comments you've been given and go with an existing application.

Building a proxy that will not interfere with the complicated web apps of today is not trivial. You also need to be careful about blocking based on keywords - web apps I've worked on have failed in spectacular ways due to proxies doing this, and rejecting requests for important javascript files (often due to minification or compression) rendering our app useless.

Also consider that your proxy won't be able to check SSL traffic (which is increasing all the time) without serving up your own certs acting as a man-in-the-middle.